# Extjs 4.1 - How to set singleExpand false in treepanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I created a treepanel has config `singleExpand: true,`

I try to change it in somewhere like `tree.singleExpand = false;` but that not working. Is that possible? how can i do that thank

Answer (score 2):

you likely have to set it to false, then updateLayout()...

`tree.singleExpand=false;`

`tree.updateLayout();`